# Invoking a method with a generic type in Kotlin with multiple parameter type constraints

Tags: java, android, generics, kotlin, interface

I have the following interface method definition written in Java:

```java
<T extends View & ISpecificView> T getSpecificView();
```

A Java-based consumer code is able to operate on this method simply by invoking it and treat the returned value as an object extending the `View` class and implementing the `ISpecificView` interface the following way:

```
getContainer().getSpecificView().whateverTclassMethod()
```

Trying to invoke the same code in Kotlin I get the `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T (...) Please specify it explicitly` error on the `getSpecificView()` method.
I'd love to provide the type explicitly, but I'm unable to pass any specific class, since it may be any ancestor of the `View` class that implements the `ISpecificView` interface. Passing either single `View` or `ISpecificView` does not help - it results in the `Type argument is not within its bounds. Expected: View! Found ICustomView` and vice versa.

Is there any possibility to pass an equivalent to Java's `T extends View & ISpecificView` in Kotlin while calling a method, so I can make use of it?

Comment: Btw, this is harder than I thought. At least for my Kotlin knowledge

Comment: I also thought that converting the Java code to Kotlin would be straight-forward, but in cases when you have a lot abstraction it gets much complicated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To recap (and I hope I got the question right!), in Java you can do

```
final View view = getContainer().getSpecificView();  // or
final ISpecificView iview = getContainer().getSpecificView();
```

In Kotlin the same thing

```
val view: View = getContainer().getSpecificView()
```

results in `Type inference failed: Not enough information to infer parameter T`

---

After 50 minutes of trying and trying...
Just create a dummy `class` (abstract?)

```
abstract class KView : View(), ISpecificView
```

And use it to explicitly set a generic return type

```
val view: View = getContainer().getSpecificView<KView>()
view.whateverClassMethod()

val iview: ISpecificView = getContainer().getSpecificView<KView>()
iview.whateverInterfaceMethod()

// or just

(getContainer().getSpecificView<KView>() as View).whateverClassMethod()
(getContainer().getSpecificView<KView>() as ISpecificView).whateverInterfaceMethod()
```

A specific cast to `View` or `ISpecificView` is required, because if you just do

```
getContainer().getSpecificView<KView>()
```

you'll get

```
class your.package$ExtendingClass cannot be cast to class your.package.KView
```

but that's is perfectly fine.
Even in Java you need to decide if you want a `View` or an `ISpecificView`.

---

This way you'll be able to operate on all the methods of `View` or `ISpecificView`.

---

Really, I don't know what else to try. Hope someone comes up with something better.

Edit: if what you mean is in Java you do

```
final ExtendedView ev = getContainer().getSpecificView();
```

well, this is a bit wrong imho, even if it compiles, as you cannot guarantee the return type is really `ExtendedView`. You just know for sure it extends `View` and implements `ISpecificView`.

Comment: This looks promising, however a bit hacky than generic solution - providing that I have to deal with several cases like this, I'd need to create a new abstract class for each interface I need to combine with the `View` class. Will check it out.

Still it would be nice to simply provide something alike `<View & ISpecificView>` for the callers. Maybe this should be a new ticket for Jetbrains?

Comment: @mrpasqal Feel free to answer there https://discuss.kotlinlang.org/t/calling-java-from-kotlin-type-inference-for-t-extends-one-two/12191

Comment: @mrpasqal I updated the answer with more precise code.

Comment: Good catch. This helps a lot. Since there is no more elegant solution in place, I'm marking this as an accepted answer. Not much elegant, but works.

It looks like Kotlin sill has to improve. Thanks for your support @LeppEdd!

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to achieve this using the following:

```
fun <T> getSpecificView() where T : View, T : ISSpecificView {}
```

Documentation for this can be found [here](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/generics.html#upper-bounds).

Comment: This is true for the declaration part, but I need this on the caller side.